# Init issue with AWS amplify cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

I am new on the AWS Amplify CLI and have successfully installed it. I have configured my profile on my local machine and given admin rights on the console.
I'm still getting this error when i try to create a new project. Can anyone tell me what the issue is ?

```
init failed
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1496:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:938:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:696:12) {
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  region: 'eu-central-1',
  hostname: 'amplify.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true,
  time: 2020-07-17T08:33:10.442Z
}
```

Comment: This is probably due to your proxy. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67180463/amplify-init-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-even-with-no-proxy